# extract string from string sql netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

please i have a column include a string as below

```
Plan
{"en_US":"Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(140GB)","ar_EG":"Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(140GB)"}
{"en_US":"Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(600GB)","ar_EG":"Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(600GB)"}
{"en_US":"Super 3 speed Up to 30Mbps Prepaid FTTH(250GB)","ar_EG":"Super 3 speed Up to 30Mbps Prepaid FTTH(250GB)"}
{"en_US":"Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(250GB)","ar_EG":"Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(250GB)"}
```

I need to extract string into 3 fields

the 1st one like below

```
Rate_Plan
Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(140GB)
Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(600GB)
Super 3 speed Up to 30Mbps Prepaid FTTH(250GB)
Ultra 2 Speed Up to 100Mbps Prepaid FTTH(250GB)
```

the 2nd one like below

```
Quota
140
600
250
250
```

the 3ed field like below

```
Speed
100
100
30
100
```

Comment: I need to extract the string from the left part before the comma

Comment: you can use the split here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the regexp_extract() function:
https://dwgeek.com/netezza-regular-expression-functions-examples.html/

In you case start with something like:
‘^([^:]*):([^:]*):.*$’ and extract pattern number two
Then extract the two other strings from that one in a similar way using something like this:
‘^.* to ([0-9])+Mbps’ (pattern 1)

I hope you can follow.